# Php - Str_replace not recognizing whitespace

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a very simple problem. I need to remove the whole

```
<td colspan="3" rowspan="1"> </td>
```

tag from html only when its empty (its not completely empty though, has some sort of whitespace). Tried to use:

```
    $html = str_replace("<td colspan=\"3\" rowspan=\"1\"> </td>","",$html);
    $html = str_replace("<td colspan=\"3\" rowspan=\"1\">&nbsp;</td>","",$html);
```

with no success.

```
    preg_replace("/<td[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/td>/", '', $html);
```

didnt work either.

It should be a fairly simple solution, any suggestions?

Comment: Try this `<td[^>]*>([\s]|&nbsp;)?<\/td>`

Comment: It should work. What do you obtain?

Comment: It just doesnt replace the html. Previously suggested preg doesnt work correctly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this? It will also match multiple spaces if present.

```
<?php

$result = preg_replace('#<td[^>]*>([\s]|&nbsp;)*<\/td>#i', '', $html);

var_dump($result);
```